# Xdebug connects to IDE when it shouldn't

Tags: xdebug

I have `remote_autostart` disabled and no cookie present:

[image: xdebug]

Still, Xdebug is connecting to my IDE (PhpStorm) at `192.168.22.101:9000` and zero-config debugging works. Why? How do I disable it? (It looks like autostart is somehow enabled and the PHP app is slow.)

Comment: What xdebug log can say about it? Maybe you have some `xdebug_break();` code left in your code?

Answer (score 1):

My first bet would be that this is not the php.ini you're looking for. If you have CLI and normal php.ini, make sure you have this set up in both. Integrated PHP server counter-intuitively uses web php.ini instead of CLI one.

Next step would be to check whether it's actually xdebug that's causing the issue. I'd do that by disabling the extension alltogether. 
Note that xdebug can slow down you app in some cases no matter what just by being enabled.

Next I'd check that xdebug profiler information is not generated. If the app is slow in general it's the profiler. If it just hangs for few seconds and then runs normally it's waiting for remote debugger. Might be a good idea to measure (even by simple means like putting dump on first and last line of code) speed of the app to rule out this possibility.

Comment: It's a live output of `phpinfo()`, not static information from php.ini. Profiling is disabled. But thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having exactly the same issue for a few days now. `remote_autostart` is set to off but it still triggers even on my own `<?php phpinfo();` script. The debugging session even starts when using an incognito browser session.

Notice the odd IDE key btw, it is set automatically.

[image: phpinfo]

Update: Even with `xdebug.default_enable` on off, it still activates Xdebug in my IDE.